# Maximum size for stack object

Tags: c++, c++11, stack

I'd like to provide an API with the following C++ struct:

```
struct fixed_string64 {
  char array[64];
};
typedef fixed_string64 st64_t;
```

Most people tell me that it is generally not a good idea to do anything that eats up lot of stack space, but then how much is "lot of" ?

In C++11, do we have something like `is_stack_hungry<st64_t>::value` ?

Comment: The answer to this question is completely system-dependent. To a uC, 128 bytes might be an inconceivably large stack. To a modern x86_64 system, it's small. Therefore, there is no such thing as a 'standard' `is_stack_hungry`.

Comment: As function calls can consume stack space (for local variables and possible parameters), it isn't enough to know if something takes up a big part of the stack. The environment of the stack allocation is also relevant. You can also change the stack size of a program for Windows and *nix after compilation, so that test most likely had to be a run-time function anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Size of the stack is implementation defined, and I am not aware of the standard way to get that information from the system/or compiler. However, most of the compilers should allow you to set the stack size (like `--stack` in gcc).

However, "making the stack as large as you want"  is definitely not my advice - if you need that, then you're doing something wrong.

For example, in your example, you could just provide constructor and destructor in order to allocate and free memory.

```
struct fixed_string64 {
  char* array;

  fixed_string64(){
    array = new char[64];
  }


  ~fixed_string64(){
    delete [] array;
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm a little bit worried that people will take this answer to mean "just make your stack as large as you want", and I don't think that's necessarily good advice.

Comment: That is certainty not a good advice, I will make that note. Thanks

Comment: $ gcc -Wl,--stack=0x80000 t.c
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--stack=0x80000'
is this supposed to work on elf/linux ?

Comment: @malat It seems that this is not working on Linux, however, on Windows it works (just I don't know how reliable is it).

Comment: on linux, stack size is set by loader when you *run* your process, not when you compile it. You can set this with `ulimit -s` in bash or `limit stacksize` in csh (google those for detailed help). BTW on these systems 64 bytes is not an problem.